# How to interpret the volume in stock candles chart?

Tags: stock-markets, trading-volume

I'm a bit confused about the numbers shown in volume. Take this chart for example:

[image]

You can see in daily candle the volume is 14M but if I show 1h candles and sum all the 7 candles of the day the volume is less than 1M !
**Why is that?**
I thought the volume was the total number of shares (not lots) transacted in that time.

EDIT: This is the 1h candles in investing, which shows 14M in volume for the 7h, which is OK with the daily volume. So maybe Tradingview.com is not showing the correct volume in 1h candles???

[image]

Comment: FWIW on https://www.investing.com/equities/alibaba-candlestick switching between time periods the volume seems to add up to the daily on 3/1 as you'd expect.

Comment: @HartCO is just a normal chart in TradingView, and yes, I know the volume is a different bar char, is shown on the image, you have the candles and the volume, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: If the data  provider shows a different total for the sum of intraday data versus the daily data total for that same day then they're providing bad data.

Comment: @BobBaerker is TradingView.com, I think maybe there is something extra to check? maybe the daily candles includes also the premarket transactions and them are much higher than transactions during the day?

Comment: @HartCO but have you seen my image? I have even indicated where I'm reading the volume. I'm comparing two different timeframes, daily and 1h candles, and the volume is below the candles on both charts

Comment: You'd have to inquire with their support to get an answer for what they are doing with their data, other sites get this right, so clearly they are either doing something  incorrectly or their volume numbers mean something unconventional.  This person noted an issue with intra-day volumes as well, it appears unreliable:  https://www.tradingview.com/script/EPkIK2JF-Volume-Problem/

Comment: Most of the time, pre-market trading volume is limited and is far, far smaller per hour than during regular hours - often non existent.    The exception to this would be quarterly earnings releases and the infrequent  news that triggers heavy buying or selling.  If the accuracy of the volume data is important to you, I would suggest that you contact  TradingView.com

Answer (score 1):

OK, it seems to be a problem with TradingView.com
I have contacted with their support and they said this:

> According to your chart snapshot, you are viewing data provided by
>   Cboe BZX. Please note that Cboe BZX is an electronic exchange that
>   doesn't charge per user fees for real-time data. However, such data is
>   slightly different from its official counterpart from primary
>   exchanges - it offers approximate volumes and fewer price updates.

And they are saying "slightly different" while is a HUGE difference, daily volume is 14M and intraday sum is less than 1M! that makes the volume intraday data completely useless in TradingView

Comment: Daily volume is the sum of all of the volume traded on the various exchanges.  Showing you just the volume from one exchange (BZX) is worthless info.